# Unable to upgrade my app from firebase.com

Tags: firebase

I have an app in firbase.com. I am trying to upgrade my app [name is "----server"] from firebase.com cosole to new console. My app showing in "https://www.firebase.com/account/". But it's not showing in "https://console.firebase.google.com/".

If my app shows here, then only i can import to new console. please kindly help me regarding this issue.

Comment: I think you can better contact firebase support for this.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/tlLBKCioevc